# How to select all inputs with type="text" but with specific names?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In my form, I have different types of inputs. What I want to do now is to select all text fields with specific names and then check if all were filled. For example, I have email, user name, institution and address field.

My goal is to hide a message textArea and will only show it if all of the fields mentioned have values. How can I bind all these fields such that when all these fields were filled, message textArea will show and then will hide again if any of these fields were cleared?

I'm thinking `$("input[name=email], input[name=address], input[name=username], input[name=address]")` and I don't think this is efficient.

The message textArea by the way will be populated based on the inputs from these fields.
Example:

```
To Whom It May Concern:

.......................Bunch of text preassigned................
................................................................

Regards,
username.val()<email.val()>
institution.val()
address.val()
```

Currently, in my form, if the user skipped the institution field, my textArea would look like this:

```
To Whom It May Concern:

.......................Bunch of text preassigned................
.......................Bunch of text preassigned................

Regards,
username.val()<email.val()>

address.val()
```

That way if I hide the textArea until all mentioned fields were filled, I will have my message textArea prefilled nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply a `css` class to all the target text inputs

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':text.required').on('input', function() {
    var NOTfilled = $(':text.required').filter(function() {
      return !this.value.trim();
    });
    if (NOTfilled.length) {
      $('.hidefirst').hide();
    } else {
      $('.hidefirst').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hidefirst {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="field1" class="required" />
  <input type="text" name="field2" class="required" />
  <input type="text" name="field3" class="required" />
  <input type="text" name="field4" class="required" />
  <input type="text" name="field5" class="required" />
  <input type="text" name="field6" class="required" />
  <textarea class="hidefirst" name="info">Hidden Info</textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: How could I test for spaces? I tried `if ($.trim(NOTfilled.val()) === "") {$('.hidefirst').hide();}` to check if the textarea will remain hidden if the user just supply a blank space.

Answer (score 0):

Could do something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="theForm">
    <input type="email" name="example"/>
    <input type="text" name="example"/>
</form>

<textarea id="txtArea">...</textarea>
```

**CSS:**

```
#txtArea {
    display:none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
// Whenever an input with the name example is modified
$('input[name=example]').keyup(function(){
    // Check if any input in the form with the name example is empty
    var emptyInput = $("#theForm").find('input[name=example]').filter(function(){
        return this.value === "";
    });
    // If one or more inputs named example are empty, hide the textarea, else show it.
    emptyInput.length > 0 ? $("#txtArea").hide() : $("#txtArea").show();
});
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/631rnrsy/)